# package java.nio.file does not exist but Java SDK/JRE 7 installed

Tags: java

I have run into a snag in a program I am trying to create for a project I am working on. Currently, I need to search the local directory for a file, and I saw that SDK 7 had introduced a better way to do the search through java.nio.File and PathMatcher. Unfortuntely, I have been having problems. I set up a simple code to see if I could get the PathMatcher set up for an arbitrary string the user enters (in the right format for GLOB of course). It follows:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.nio.file.*;
 import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
 import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.nio.file.*;

 public class test4{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 String pattern = args[0];
 PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
 }
}
```

This returns the following compile-time errors:

```
File: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java  [line: 2]
Error: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java:2: package java.nio.file does not exist

File: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java  [line: 3]
Error: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java:3: package java.nio.file.attribute does not exist

File: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java  [line: 4]
Error: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java:4: package java.nio.file does not exist

File: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java  [line: 7]
Error: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java:7: package java.nio.file does not exist

File: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java  [line: 13]
Error: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PathMatcher
location: class test4

File: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java  [line: 13]
Error: /Users/xenosphobos/Documents/Thesis/ThesisJava/test4.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable FileSystems
location: class test4
```

---

I am currently running MAC OSX 10.8.4 and have SDK 7.45 installed. I use the IDE DrJava (I know, I know, Eclipse is better).

When I run java -version, I get:
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Could it be my IDE? Is there a problem with Mac OSX? I guess I could use the Java 6 way of doing file searching, but this seems much easier. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Maybe Dr Java packages and uses its own JRE 6.

Comment: Java 1.5: try opening DrJava and under the compiler tab at bottom right check the version: it should say "javac 1.5.0".

Comment: You need to configure JAVA_HOME env. var. or tell the IDE which of the JDK versions installed to use.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of 'java -version' executed in a terminaL?